# Convergence of vector and matrix sequence $a_n = b_n + M_n a_{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Suppose I have a vector sequence $a_n$:

$$a_n = b_n + M_n \, a_{n-1},$$

which depends on its previous term $a_{n-1}$. Also, $\lim \,b_n = 0$ and the matrix sequence $\lim \, M_n = O$, a zero matrix as $n$ gets to the infinity.

Does the sequence $a_n$ converge? Should I impose further assumption on $a_n$ such that I can prove the convergence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean each $a_n$ and $b_n$ to be elements of $\Bbb R^d$ for some fixed $d$ that does not vary with $n$, and $M_n \in \Bbb R^d\times \Bbb R^d$ for that same value of $d$.  RIght?

Comment: yes. I appreciate so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and also use this to denote the induced matrix norm on $\mathbb{R}^{d}\times \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Then for $\varepsilon>0$, when $n$ sufficiently large, we have by the assumptions on $b_{n}$ and $M_{n}$ that $\|b_{n}\|<\varepsilon$ and $\|M_{n}\|<\varepsilon$. That means that (using the triangle inequality and consistency of the induced matrix norm with the vector norm): $$\|a_{n}\|\leq \|b_{n}\|+\|M_{n}a_{n-1}\|\leq \|b_{n}\|+\|M_{n}\|\|a_{n-1}\|\leq \varepsilon(1+\|a_{n-1}\|).$$ Then we see that $$\limsup_{n\geq 1} \|a_{n}\|\leq \varepsilon\left(1+\limsup_{n\geq 1}\|a_{n}\|\right),$$ or in other words, $$(1-\varepsilon)\limsup_{n\geq1}\|a_{n}\|\leq \varepsilon.$$ Letting $\varepsilon$ drop to 0, we see that $a_{n}\rightarrow0$ is the only possibility as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not understand the inequality after "Then we see that", why $\| a_{n-1}\|$ becomes $limsup \| a_n\|$. Would you please tell me the clue? Thank you.

Comment: I'm just taking the limsup as $n\rightarrow\infty$ on both sides of the inequality. When $n\rightarrow\infty$, so does $n-1$.